# Why does the implementation of AsyncRead on Box have an Unpin trait bound?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The implementation of `AsyncRead` (tokio) on `Box`ed types has the following signature:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized + AsyncRead + Unpin> AsyncRead for Box<T>
```

Why is `Unpin` required here by the trait bound? Why isn't the address stability ensured by `Box` enough?

Comment: You can move out of boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is Unpin required here by the trait bound?

Plain old `Box<T>` is not pinned, so any async operations it generates will require that the underlying `T` does not care about pinning (i.e. is `Unpin`).

> Why isn't the address stability ensured by Box enough?

You can move or replace the object in a plain `Box`, which would break the stability guarantee. `Pin` does not allow `mut` access without `unsafe`, preventing the value from escaping.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is `Unpin` required here by the trait bound?

The `poll_read()` method on `AsyncRead` accepts a receiver with the type `Pin<&mut Self>`. If we want to be able to forward the call to the wrapped type, we need to convert `Pin<&mut Box<T>>` to `Pin<&mut T>`, i.e. we need to get a mutable reference pointing into the box. This is only possible if `T` is `Unpin`.

> Why isn't the address stability ensured by `Box` enough?

`Unpin` is the opposite of address stability. If `T` is `Unpin`, instances of `T` can be moved even when pinned.